# "Finally" not executed on pycharm stop button; is there another way to clean up nicely?

Tags: python, execute, termination

I am using PyCharm and I have a question. In the code bellow, I created a class that will connect to a server and run a client inside the game_loop method, and a method that will disconnect me from that server. After I am done, I press the button on the PyCharm interface to stop the program, but the code from the finally does not run, and I remain connected to the server 2-3 seconds until it crashes.
I wish to be able to exit in the same way I exit now, by terminating the process and after that, somehow, to run the function terminate_all()

```
class Game(object):
    def game_loop(self):
        # Connect to server

        while True:
            try:
                # Run the client
                pass
            finally:
                self.terminate_all()

    def terminate_all(self):
        # Disconnect from the server
        pass


def main():
    try:
        game_loop()
    finally:
        print('EXIT')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can this be done?
I searched and not found anything like this, so I came here.

Comment: When you stop the code in Pycharm you stop the whole thing, so no further code will be executed. The obvious answer is 'don't use the stop button'. What you actually need is a 'disconnect' button so I'd suggest you implement this yourself.

Comment: Depends on _how_ you're getting stopped. It's possible to trap a SIGTERM and implement your own handler; whereas a SIGKILL can't be ignored or delayed. Would need to know details of pycharm's implementation to know just how it terminates its child processes.

Comment: Pressing the Stop button sends SIGINT on first press and SIGKILL on second. You may be able to handle it using the `signal` built-in module, but only on Unix-based OSes. As a Windows dev, my solution was to run in via command line using WSL so that I could handle signals.